# Hard drive doesn't work in caddy after about 10 minutes of start up

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have Lenovo G510.
I am using WD 1TB hard drive since 2 years.

I bought new SSD and replace SSD with HDD and then replace the CD Drive with that 1TB Hard inside Universal Caddy.

Initially I was getting problem the drive doesn't show in Windows 10. I reseated the Caddy once again after that it started showing up.

Now it shows the secondary HDD but after start up it stops working like I get 100% active time, and 0 read and write.

There is flip in universal Caddy in which there are 3 states and I have set in the middle, but the problem is still there that HDD that I was using from years stops working inside caddy after 10 minutes startup.

What can be the issue?

**EDIT**

Event Logged As :

Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.

Comment: try a different caddy and look if you have the same issue

Comment: do you recommend any caddy ? i am using this one https://www.amazon.com/SATA-caddy-12-7mm-Universal-DVD-ROM/dp/B0056EW4A4

Comment: mine looks similar and I have no issues. try to update the BIOS